# How to store a select sql result record in list in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table employee. below query return one record, want to store it in a list so that latter on i can iterate it and fetch the value.

```
select employee_name,employee_surname from employee where emp_id = '123';
```

something like

```
select employee_name,employee_surname bulk collect into list_emp from employee where emp_id = '123';
.
.
FOR indx IN 1 .. list_emp.count
 LOOP
<other sqls>
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you know that you can use the query as a subquery in other queries, e.g. `select * from other_table where (name, surname) in (select employee_name, employee_surname from employee where emp_id = 123);`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by declaring a package level collection of record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_emp_rec AS
    TYPE emp_rec IS RECORD ( employee_name employee.employee_name%TYPE,
    employee_surname employee.employee_surname%TYPE );
    TYPE list_emptype IS
        TABLE OF emp_rec;
    list_emp list_emptype;
END pkg_emp_rec;
```

Next you can store and retrieve from this collection in whichever block/procedure you want.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN
    SELECT
        employee_name,
        employee_surname
    BULK COLLECT INTO
        pkg_emp_rec.list_emp
    FROM
        employee;

    FOR indx IN 1..pkg_emp_rec.list_emp.count 
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(pkg_emp_rec.list_emp(indx).employee_name);
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

**Note:** This is not recommended when your table data is huge. It is always better to fetch from the database table than collections. Only take this as a solution for your homework.

Another approach is to store the employee names as a nested table column, which I give you as an assignment.